# How do these crypto websites get the current real time price and volume information?

Tags: api

If I want to get the latest pricing for Solana, BTC and other crypto's, is there a uniform API to do this or do I have to connect to some open exchange to get this information?

For starters, how would I get Solana current price and volume information?
Is actual individual trades also available and is this free?

Comment: To prevent this question from being closed, please add clarifying details such as the place from which you want to obtain this information (eg. a JavaScript service, a web application, a Python script)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get that data inside Solana Program or in just web2 API ?
For API there are many price API endpoints. [Coingecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api) being very popular one

If you need a price inside solana program you can take a look at [Pyth price feed oracles](https://pyth.network/price-feeds?cluster=solana-mainnet-beta). They have 96 price feeds currently available to query on Solana mainnet-beta

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TVYuf_RMa0) is a simple youtube tutorial on how to do it